# How to access DotnetNuke.Entities.Users from javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, json, dotnetnuke

I want to collect userInfo from Dotnetnuke to my javascript webpage.
To collect it I utilize $.getJSON:

```
$.getJSON("/DesktopModules/myModule/API/Service/GetUsers", "portalId=2",
    function (allData) {
        var mappedUsers = $.map(allData, function (item) {
            return new myModule.User(item);
        });
        self.Users(mappedUsers);
    });
```

I have this service controller:

```
public class ServiceController : DnnApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetUsers(int portalId)
    {
        myController controller = new myController();
        ArrayList items = controller.GetUsers(portalId);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, items);
    }
}

public class myController // : ISearchable, IPortable
{
    public ArrayList GetUsers(int portalId)
    { 
        return UserController.GetUsers(portalId);
    }
}
```

According to the DNN API documentation the method is defined as:

```
public static ArrayList GetUsers(
     int portalId
)
```

But when I test my service in a browser it fails with an error:
"Type 'DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserInfo' with data contract name 'UserInfo:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DotNetNuke.Entities.Users' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer."

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't serialize the UserInfo without setting up a custom serialization.  The UserInfo object cannot be serialized to JSON automatically.

The simplest solution would be to create your own object representing the UserInfo in your response - either a cut down class or just the individual properties you need.